# ListBox selected Items list not shown

Tags: listbox, selected

Hi I am using the following code to show data in list box and when a user selects items in it and presses a forward key(button) I take the selected items and show them in a another listbox, but Unfortunately I am getting empty string for selected values.

**Code:-**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;

public partial class AssignRolesToUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<int,string> roles = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        roles.Add(1,"Manager");
        roles.Add(2,"ASM");
        roles.Add(3,"SM");
        roles.Add(4,"RM");
        Dictionary<int, string> Users = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Users.Add(1,"Ganesh");
        Users.Add(2,"ABC");
        Users.Add(3,"XYZ");
        Users.Add(4,"DEF");
        Users.Add(5,"MNO");
        ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
        ListBox1.DataSource = Users.Values;
        ListBox1.DataBind();
        ComboBox1.DataSource = roles.Values;
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        ComboBox1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // GetSelectedIndices
        List<string> AU = new List<string>();
        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                AU.Add(ListBox1.SelectedValue);
            }  
        }
        ListBox2.DataSource = AU;
        ListBox2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
int[] iMyList = Listbox.GetSelectedIndices();
//iMyList.length
//iMyList[0]
//Combo.items[iMyList[0]] -  OR CLOSE
```

It is the array(list) of selected items indexes, which you can use to fetch the actual value or text.

Comment: hi Anthony, I could not find any selecteditems property in the properties. I am using ListBox on ASPX page.

Comment: Can I use this technique:- i want to populate data in DDL and LISTBOX1 in Pageload from codebehind, after that when user selects items and presses a buton I would handle it on client side, get the data from listbox1 and pass selected data to listbox2. which I think I can find over internet. What I don't understand is how do I get data populated in listbox2 from serverside, or how do I pass it to serverside on a final savebtn click.(I Hope I am clear).

Comment: There is also a changeevent on the listbox, which you can monitor and will give you the current change / selected. etc.

Comment: No Anthony, the idea is to absolutely reduce round trips to server, the users of this application are impatient so I need to ensure that all that they want to do with data should not involve round trips to server, instead I let them do all the work in browser without round trip and finally when they click save button it should save on server.

Comment: Cool. Don't discount there use of Ajax for this. Your app tends to feel client side due to the partial posting.